# Listing files timestamped within last two hours in Python

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, timestamp, filemtime

I have a directory full of files that are generated every 5 minutes. When I do an ls -l at a cmd prompt I can see the files and their last modified time.

I need to programatically get a list of files that are timestamped within the last N minutes. How to do that?

Comment: Did you even try anything yourself?

Comment: No, I have not tried. I have never done file manipulation in python before (I am a bit of a noob)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`os.path.getmtime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.getmtime) or [`os.path.getctime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.getctime) to get modification / creation time of the file.

```
import os
import time

dirpath = '/path/to/dir'
past = time.time() - 2*60*60 # 2 hours
result = []
for p, ds, fs in os.walk(dirpath):
    for fn in fs:
        filepath = os.path.join(p, fn)
        if os.path.getmtime(filepath) >= past:
            result.append(filepath)
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: The answer posted by falsetru recurses from dirpath down through all subdirs. to do this to a specific dir, dirpath in this case, use

```
import os
import time

dirpath = '/path/to/dir'
past = time.time() - 2*60*60 # 2 hours
result = []
result = [ f for f in listdir(dirpath) if ((isfile(join(dirpath,f))) and (os.path.getmtime(join(dirpath,f)) >= past)) ]
```